# Hibernate Envers audit @Embedded with basic types inside throws cannot set field to null value on fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-envers

I have and audited entity with a foreign key to a class (which I don't want to audit):

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class CitaAgenda {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reconocimiento_id")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private Reconocimiento reconocimiento;
    ...
}
```

Also, `Reconocimiento` is an entity with an embedded property:

```
@Entity
public class Reconocimiento {
     @Embedded
     private Enfermeria enfermeria;
     ...
}
```

And the embeddable class is as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class Enfermeria {
    private boolean diabetes;
    ...
}
```

Now, when I bring the data from the revisions and fetch *CitaAgenda*, I get a

> "Can not set boolean field ...Enfermeria.diabetes to null value".

What I think it is happening is that Hibernate tries to init the *enfermeria* property of *Reconocimiento* with NULL because it believes all fields are NULL as the only field of *Reconocimiento* stored in the `_AUD` table is the ID (as the others are not audited). But this is not true as if I audit the other fields, *diabetes* would be *false* and not NULL.

I cannot set *diabetes* to Boolean. Are there any other solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add annotations to Enfemeria?

Comment: @Javi_Swift do you have a bi-directional mapping here? If so `@NotAudited` on Reconocimiento is what you want i believe

Comment: @Eugene that is not my case, but thank you for trying

Comment: @Javi_Swift if the solution below works for you, would you mind submitting a JIRA so that I can address this from an Envers perspective to avoid necessarily having to use a `Converter` ?

Comment: @Naros Link to the issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11429 (this is the first time I use JIRA so sorry if there is any mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can add additional annotations to Enfemeria then you could mark it with a custom converter:

**Embedded class**

```
@Convert(converter=MyBooleanConverter.class)
private boolean diabetes;
```

**Converter class**

```
@Converter
public class MyBooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Integer>{
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value)) {
            return Integer.valueOf(1);
        } else {
            return Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(Integer value) {
        if(value != null and value.equals(1){
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }

        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

Of course you may need to consider using String instead of Integer for converting. It depends on the underlying column data type in your database.

Comment: I can add annotations and I did it. I had to change some things in the converter due to the types I have in my DB implementation (Postgresql) but it is working fine now. Thanks!